# How to download all pics in this website: huaban.com

Tags: python, html, web-applications, libcurl, webclient

I want to use a script to get all those pictures in this website. I viewed the source code of he main page with chrome developer tools. These image urls are like

```
src="http://img.hb.aicdn.com/3e32a8b101e515b9e7dbe8f5a2e47afff5ec6bcf4e4a-OTvsuu_fw192
```

But if i use `wget` or `curl` to download this page or even "Save pave" in browser, there is no such link in that html file. I don't know how to get all those links. Another problem is if we scroll down the page, images comes out continuous. I don't know if there is any way to get the whole page.

Comment: "there is no such link in that html files"? Means what exactly?

Comment: if the html returned from wget has not got the links in and they keep appearing as you scroll i would guess that they are dynamically loaded using javascript. As such you would need a library that can run javascript before you parse the html, or copy the 'generated' source from a browser.

Comment: means there is no img urls in downloaded html.

Comment: As a first step, I think that you should look at what the generated HTML that you actually download shows. Some websites serve up different pages without JavaScript, or adopt other schemes to prevent hot linking of their content. It would be instructive to see if the returned HTML is the same basic page, or an error message of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please post the URL to the final page where you want to donwload all pics?

Or to you mean *all images from the http://huaban.com/ landing page*?

With the following code you can 'save' the image url into a file on your filesystem:

```
image_path = 'http://img.hb.aicdn.com/3e32a8b101e515b9e7dbe8f5a2e47afff5ec6bcf4e4a-OTvsuu_fw192'
with open(r'<path_to_file>.jpg', 'wb') as image:
    image.write(urllib2.urlopen(image_path).read())
```

But to retrieve the image 'source' pathes ... I fear they will be generated by the javascript components, so you have not much alternatives.

Maybe one solution could be to use a *headless browser* or JavaScript Engine bridge like [Python-Spidermonkey](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/) to get the final (js-buidled) html-content.

-Colin-

Comment: yeah, i know what you mean. What i want to do is get all image links in this main page, like `http://huaban.com/pins/17989365/`, and then use this link to get link like `http://huaban.com/pins/17989365/zoom/`, and finally download the large picture in this page. Thanks.

Comment: As I've updated my post, I fear that you have to use a headless browser or JavaScript Engine bridge like Python-Spidermonkey to request and parse the final (<img/src> tag included) html content. But setting up a spidermonkey environment neither is easy nor trivial, because the installation of that library contains a C-compilation part. Are you familiar with *setup* python libaries from source including c-compilations?

Comment: OK, i will try that. A little tricky.